# SQL query to return some values from the second table and use other values in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables as follows

Vehicle table

```
Vehicle_id | Location | Status
------------------------------
1000       | FLT1     | OPERATING
1001       | FLT1     | OPERATING
.          |   .      | .
.          |   .      | .
```

and 
Vehicle_Specs table

```
Vehicle_id | AttribID | AttribValue
------------------------------
1000       | Model     | F150
1000       | Driver    | John Smith
1000       | Odometer  | 80000
1001       | Model     | F350
1001       | Driver    | Joe Douglas
1001       | Odometer  | 50000
```

I have difficulties to acheive the following objective using SQL.

return all vehicle_ids and its driver where the vehicle status is Operating and its model is F150. My problem is to how to create a subquery to get two AtrribValues in the second table in my select statement and where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the same table more than once in the query:

```
SELECT V.Vehicle_id, drivers.AttribValue AS Driver
FROM Vehicle V
    JOIN Vehicle_Specs drivers ON V.Vehicle_id = drivers.Vehicle_id AND drivers.AttribId = 'Driver'
    JOIN Vehicle_Specs models ON V.Vehicle_id = models.Vehicle_id AND models.AttribId = 'Model'
WHERE models.AttribValue = 'F150' AND V.Status = 'OPERATING'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `PIVOT` then you will only need a single table scan of the Vehicle_specs table:

```
SELECT v.vehicle_id,
       s.Driver
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   Vehicle_specs
         PIVOT  ( MAX( attribvalue )
                  FOR AttribID IN ( 'Model' AS model, 'Driver' AS Driver ) )
       ) s
       INNER JOIN
       vehicle v
       ON ( v.vehicle_id = s.vehicle_id )
WHERE  s.model  = 'F150'
AND    v.status = 'OPERATING'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, those horrible key/value tables. They make you read the same table again and again and again.

The query is rather easy, though:

```
select vehicle_id, attribvalue as driver
from vehicle_specs
where vehicle_id in 
  (select vehicle_id from vehicle where status = 'OPERATING')
and vehicle_id in 
  (select vehicle_id from vehicle_specs where attribid = 'Model' and attribvalue = 'F150')
and attribid = 'Driver';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select V2.Vehicle_id, V2.AttribValue
from Vehicle V1
inner join Vehicle_specs V2
    on V1.Vehicle_id = V2.Vehicle_id
where Status = 'Operating'
and exists (select 1 
            from Vehicle_Specs V3 
            where V3.vehicle_id = V2.Vehicle_id 
            and V3.Attribid = 'Model' 
            and V3.AttribValue = 'F150')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT V.Vehicle_id, Specs.AttribId, Specs.AttribValue FROM Vehicle V
LEFT JOIN Vehicle_Specs Specs ON Specs.Vehicle_id = V.Vehicle_id AND Specs.AttribId='Driver'
WHERE V.Status='OPERATING' AND V.Vehicle_id IN (SELECT Vehicle_id FROM Vehicle_Specs WHERE AttribId='Model' AND AttribValue='F150');
```

Comment: Neither of these queries returns the driver.

Comment: @MT0 You are right, I missread the question. I've updated the answer

Comment: Using `@` before table names is not valid in Oracle.

Comment: @MT0 Right you are, that was a left over from my mockup in MSSQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has already been solved sufficiently.

I would only to you recommend normalization of databases. The reason why you should normalize is to avoid redundancies and to maintain the consistency of data.

Redundancy e.g.:

```
Vehicle_id | Location | Status
------------------------------ 
1000       | FLT1     | OPERATING
1001       | FLT1     | OPERATING
```

For n records with status 'OPERATING' you save n times 'OPERATING'.
But that is not necessary. Instead, you can move the status to another table and refer to it.

- denormalized databases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization
- third normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

---

Normalized:

**Vehicle** table: (for vehicle specific attributes)

```
v_id | m_id | odometer | ...
------------------------------------------
1000 | 0001 | 80000    | ...
1001 | 0002 | 50000    | ...
...
```

**Model** table: (for model specific attributes)

```
m_id | model | ...
------------------
0001 | F150  | ...
0002 | F350  | ...
...
```

**Status** table: (for status specific attributes)

```
s_id | status
------------
0001 | OPERATING
0002 | ...
...
```

**Driver** table: (for driver specific attributes)

```
d_id | first_name | last_name | ...
-----------------------------------
0001 | John       | Smith     | ...
0002 | Joe        | Douglas   | ...
...
```

**VehicleDriver** table:

```
vd_id | v_id | d_id | s_id
--------------------------
0001  | 1000 | 0001 | 0001
0002  | 1001 | 0002 | 0001
```

The SQL statement for the normalized database could look like this:

```
SELECT vehicle.v_id, first_name, last_name 
FROM driver, vehicle, vehicledriver, status, model
WHERE vehicle.v_id = vehicledriver.v_id
AND vehicledriver.d_id = driver.d_id
AND vehicledriver.s_id = status.s_id
AND vehicle.m_id = model.m_id
AND status = "OPERATING"
AND model = "F150";
```

Result:

```
v_id | first_name | last_name
--------------------------
0001 | John       | Smith
```

Comment: for the sake of simplicity I did not include all the fields and related tables to exactly reflect the exact logic. This comes from IBM asset management database that is designed this way (right or wrong) but I agree with your suggestion.